# Python and Selenium form automation - modal won't stay open

Tags: python, selenium, automation, modal-dialog

I am using Python and Selenium to automate filling out a form. When it clicks on a button to bring up a modal, you can see it flash briefly but then it closes immediately. It behaves as though I have clicked somewhere to close the modal.

I receive an error stating that *WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'tbSearchAll')))* input gives a TimeoutException, which makes sense given that the modal does not stay open.

The only difference between this modal and earlier ones in the code is that this modal has an input field for searching which asynchronously populates a table of options.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to keeping this modal open? What am I missing here?

[Button that controls modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVTCm.png)

[Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRcxz.png)

```
for doc in florida.docs:
    #Determine search term
    if (doc[1]):
        searchTerm = doc[1]
    else:
        searchTerm = doc[0]
       
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'btnAddDocument')))
    driver.find_element_by_id('btnAddDocument').click()
    #Search
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'tbSearchAll')))
    driver.find_element_by_id('tbSearchAll').send_keys(searchTerm + '\n')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="' + doc[4] + '"]')))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="' + doc[4] + '"]').click()
    #Upload document
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located\
    ((By.ID, 'ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_bcph_mca_docca_documentsAddEditControl_documentUploadFrame')))
    iframe = 'documentUploadFrame'
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'docAddEditfileinput')))
    driver.find_element_by_id('docAddEditfileinput').send_keys(doc[3])

    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.find_element_by_id('btnSaveDocument').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'nextButtonLeadDocument')))
driver.find_element_by_id('nextButtonLeadDocument').click()
```

Comment: Couldn't that be an application issue ? what happens when you try manually ?

Comment: No problems using it manually, so I don't think it's an application issue.

Comment: Is URL public ?

Comment: No. It requires login. A site for filing legal documents.

Comment: You can try to put `driver.implicitly_wait(30)` somewhere in your code, but would be difficult to imagine in order to solve this issue.

Comment: If I click the button a second time, the modal stays open, but this line is skipped. driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="' + doc[4] + '"]').click() and I receive an error when trying to save that it was not selected.

Comment: also, I see you are using duplicate line of code, such as `WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'btnAddDocument')))` returns a web element where as you are duplicating here as `driver.find_element_by_id('btnAddDocument').click()`, instead it should have been like `WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'btnAddDocument'))).click()`

Comment: Noted. I am new at this. Appreciate that.